# Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound "apoc.nodes.cycles"

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am having an error when trying to use APOC library function apoc.nodes.cycles. It says that there is no procedure found with that name. When listing the procedures found I get the following [image: List of procedures]

As you can see there is no procedure called apoc.nodes.cycles even tho the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.nodes/) says otherwise. When calling apoc.version() I get version 5.12.0 and my neo4j version is 5.3.0. I am using Neo4j Desktop 1.5.9. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

**EDIT**

Now I am a bit confused. When I said I am running Neo4J version 5.3.0 I was referring to this: [image: picture].

But now that I found another one saying I am running version 5.12.0: [image: New pic][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QArM.png).

This means I am running compatible as per @cybersam comment. But still not able to find the procedure.

Comment: The apoc and neo4j versions should be compatible. Try deleting apoc 5.12.0 and installing apoc 5.3.0, or upgrading neo4j to 5.12.0.

Comment: @cybersam please check edit on my question. Turns out I do have compatible versions.

Comment: The `DBMSs` displayed by the Desktop are just the neo4j versions that are stored locally for faster installation of new neo4j instances, and can be deleted to free up space. It is true that the heading "DBMSs" is very ambiguous.

Comment: @cybersam Thanks for the clarification, but does it mean that I have neo4j version 5.3 or 5.12? and if 5.3 will a simple upgrade solve my problem? :)

Comment: You can run this  to check the neo4j version you are using at the moment: `call dbms.components()`. I would  keep everything at the latest version. If convenient, you can try creating a new Project in the Desktop with 5.12.0, and see if you can see `apoc.nodes.cycles`. You may have something munged in your current installation.